# How do I modify a search query in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I am using WordPress and have a search box in the header. It searches on the basis of posts. Now I want to modify this search box with a cities drop down search box. I also added a new cities table in the database. I need to run the search box on the basis of cities.

Comment: Could you please give us more details so that we can help you. Did you try also some code already? Can we see it? How is the structure of your database in relation to the cities table?

Comment: yes , Please see this link:http://clouds.cloudneon.com/

you can see second search box which required to search ad on basis of states. I looking for search query which is responsible for search result. I also can see some parameters in query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have made a special table for locations you are probably going to need your own search query and start from that one to develop your needs.

A good start would be to create a new template file to which you are going to submit your search form, and a search function in functions.php which is a mandatory file in your theme.

A good example on how to do that I found in *[Search Multiple Custom Fields in WordPress](http://matthewaprice.com/search-multiple-custom-fields-in-wordpress/)*.

However, you might ask: Why do you need to write a special search function for that? You said you have added a new table in the database that is not part of the default taxonomy system of WordPress so that one is not going to take into consideration your extra parameters of the search.

Moreover I do not recommend you to modify the core search function, because at some particular time you would probably like to make an upgrade or so, and that is going to mess up with your search. The *functions.php* file way is the safer way and yields results faster.

Answer (score 13):

You can simply add following code in your `functions.php` file in your WordPress theme directory.

```
function searchfilter($query) {

if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {
    $query->set('post_type',array('trip'));
}

return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');
```

Here `trip` is my custom post type and now default search function of WordPress will only search in custom post type `trip`.
You can modify it according to your requirements.

Comment: just a short correction: the `$query` var does not need to be returned. you `->get` and `->set` parameters and that's it. no need to return.